# IOException: Size of the state is larger than the maximum permitted memory-backed state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am facing the following IO exception while running a simple wordcount 
application over apache flink in cluster mode.

> IOException: Size of the state is larger than the maximum permitted 
>   memory-backed state. Size=34521369 , maxSize=5242880 . Consider using a 
>   different state backend, like the File System State backend.

I have already using filesystem state backend and configured the checkpoint 
and state backend directories.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How did you configure the state backend?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace, please? This should actually not happen in the case of the FsStateBackend.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the FSStateBackend is a bit misnamed in that it actually uses the heap for state, only using the file system for checkpoints. If you have a large amount of state you should instead consider:

- Increasing the heap allocated to the JVM
- Using the RocksDB state backend, which is off-heap and uses storage
- Distribute your job across additional Task Managers on other machines